# How update OwlCarousel's items in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using react-owl-carousel package.

While update state, couldnt update items 
how can i fix this

```
componentDidMount(){
   ...update state with ajax data
}

let items = this.state.items.map((data, index)=>{
    return (<div className="item" key={index}>
        <h2>Q{data.quarter}</h2>
        <h5>{data.year}</h5>
    </div>)
});


<OwlCarousel
    className="owl-theme owl-carousel fr"
    {...this.state.options}>
    {items}
</OwlCarousel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just call `setState` once the ajax call finishes:

```
componentDidMoun() {
  ajaxCall().then((items) => this.setState({ items }));
}
```